# Why is the destructor not called?

Tags: c++, stack

This is logical, create object on the stack... copy of object is return, original is deleted

```
Box operator +(const Box& box) const 
{
    Box b = Box(this->num + box.num);
    return b;                        
}  // destructor called!
```

Why in this case is the the process different??

```
Box operator +(const Box& box) const 
{
    return Box(this->num + box.num);
}   // destructor not called!
```

Why is the destructor not called in the second operator overloading method?

Comment: How are you using this function? Are you assigning the result?

Comment: Box box1 = box2+box3;

Comment: Look up "return value optimisation."

Comment: @JavaNewb: Then for some reason your compiler does not perform NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization) in the first case

Comment: It isn't a "deconstructor", it is a "destructor". :)

Comment: It is called «destructor». There is no such thing as «deconstructor».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What your seeing is the compiler not bothering to create the temporary object by performing a [return-value-optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Answer (score 5):

The destructor is not called because the compiler can perform "Return Value Optimization" here. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization for details.